# RxJS combine streams and use value of both to call a third

Tags: angular, redux, observable, rxjs5

I've got an Angular 2 application where I have an 'AlgemeneInfoService' with a getAlgemeneInfo() method that returns an Observable.

Using angular-redux/store, I've got a store that has a 'Dossier' and 'Verpleegperiode' object in it, both having an Id that the AlgemeneInfoService uses to get the 'AlgemeneInfo' object. (the VerpleegperiodeId can be null)

**I'm trying to put the ActiveAlgemeneInfo, which should be refreshed by calling the AlgemeneInfoService when the state-object of either Dossier or Verpleegperiode changes, in the state-object.**

My plan was using an ActiveAlgemeneInfoService that handles these subscriptions and has a method getActiveAlgemeneInfo() which returns the 'selectedAlgemeneInfo' that is set with a subscription to the ActiveAlgemeneInfo state object:

```
@select(state => state.dieet.activeAlgemeneInfo) 
private activeAlgemeneInfo$: Observable<AlgemeneInfo>;
```

In the constructor of the service, I set the subscriptions:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.activeInfohosVerpleegperiode$,
  this.activeInfohosDossier$
)
.distinctUntilChanged()
.subscribe(([v, d]) => {
  const verpleegperiodeId = v != null ? v.verpleegperiodeId : null;
  const dossierId = d.dossierId;
  console.log(`vp id: ${verpleegperiodeId} - d id: ${dossierId}`);
  this._setActiveAlgemeneInfo(dossierId, verpleegperiodeId);
});

this.activeAlgemeneInfo$.subscribe(algemeneInfo => this.selectedAlgemeneInfo = algemeneInfo);
```

And in the service, I've also got a method:

```
private _setActiveAlgemeneInfo = (dossierId: number, verpleegperiodeId: number) => {
this._algemeneInfoService
  .getAlgemeneInfo(dossierId, verpleegperiodeId)
  .subscribe(algemeneInfo => this._dieetActions.selectAlgemeneInfo(algemeneInfo));
}
```

When the service is constructed and the method getActiveAlgemeneInfo() is called:

```
public getActiveAlgemeneInfo = (): Observable<AlgemeneInfo> => {
     return this.activeAlgemeneInfo$;
}
```

it just spams http requests, while when I console.log the Observable.combineLatest(), the Dossier and Verpleegperiode are exactly the same as the previous request.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `distinctUntilChanged` - because it does not do a *"deep" comparison*, it only compares the reference - and for `combineLatest` this will always be a new array.

Try the following and see if that helps with your issue:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.activeInfohosVerpleegperiode$.distinctUntilChanged(),
  this.activeInfohosDossier$.distinctUntilChanged()
)
.subscribe(([v, d]) => {
```

---

Alternatively you should provide a compare-method that does perform a deep-comparison like so:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
  this.activeInfohosVerpleegperiode$,
  this.activeInfohosDossier$
)
.distinctUntilChanged(_.isEqual) // from: https://lodash.com/docs/#isEqual
.subscribe(([v, d]) => {
```